# Where can I find MySQL logs in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, logging, phpmyadmin

Where can I find the MySQL's logs (errors, queries, etc.) in the phpMyAdmin interface?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open your PHPMyAdmin, don't select any database and look for `Binary Log` tab .
You can select different logs from a drop down list and press `GO` Button to view them.

Comment: I have Databases,SQL,Status,Variables,Charsets,Engines,Processes,Export & Import tabs but no 'Binary Log' - am I looking in the correct location?

Comment: HUmm, I have Privileges and Binary log between Engines and Processes. are you using WAMP? Which version? Are you loged in with root?

Comment: ah, probably restricted by my hosts then.  I will ask them, thankyou for your help.

Comment: I can't find a `Binary Log tab` ! nor any tab related to logs !

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana, it's under the 'Status' tab. If you click on that and then look at the list items above 'Server Traffic' you'll see 'Binary Log' between 'Threads' and 'Temporary data'.

Comment: There is no "Binary Log" under the Status tab, if there once was.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem of @rutherford, today the new phpMyAdmin's 3.4.11.1 GUI is different, so I figure out it's better if someone improves the answers with updated info.

Full mysql logs can be found in:

> "Status"->"Binary Log"

This is the answer, doesn't matter if you're using MAMP, XAMPP, LAMP, etc.

Comment: If this was once true, it no longer is. The options under Status are Server, Processes, Query statistics, All status variables, Monitor, Advisor. There is no "Binary Log" option.

Answer (score 20):

I am using phpMyAdmin version 4.2.11. At the time of writing, my `Status` tab looks like this (a few options expanded; note "Current settings", bottom right):

[image: Image of Status Panel]

Note, there are no directly visible "features" that allow for the enabling of things such as `slow_query_log`. So, I went digging on the internet because UI-oriented answers will only be relevant to a particular release and, therefore, will quickly become out of date. So, what do *you* do if you **don't** see a relevant answer, above?

As this [article explains](http://blog.skunkbad.com/databases/mysql/enable-general-and-slow-query-logging), you can run a global query to enable or disable the `slow_query_log` et al. *The queries for enabling and disabling these logs are not difficult, so don't be afraid of them*, e.g.

`SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';`

From here, phpMyAdmin is pretty helpful and a bit of Googling will get you up to speed in no time. For instance, after I ran the above query, I can go back to the "Instructions/Setup" option under the Status tab's `Monitor` window and see this (note the further instructions):

[image: Slow query enabled]

Comment: This answer looked good as it was exactly my case. Unfortunately, it won't always work as you need SUPER privileges:
"Error
SQL query:
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON'
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"

Comment: This is a terrific answer, if your problem isn't that you need to see the logs because PHPmyAdmin is erroring out with a 403 every time you try to run a SQL query. Like it is for me. Can't run SQL statements because I get a 403, can't troubleshoot the 403 error because the log option isn't there, can't turn the logs on because I need to run a SQL statement to do it, can't run SQL statements because I get a 403....

Comment: I did discover you can run `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON'` and `SET GLOBAL log_output = 'ON'`from the console in the bottom of that status page. Having done these, I now have exactly nothing different and no visible way to see any "binary log" or other log of any kind that I can detect, and still absolutely no way that I can find anywhere to view any kind of log for PHPmyAdmin. I am totally unclear why there are features to turn "logging" on when there is apparently no log output at all (at least, none that anything on the internet, including the linked article, mentions.)

Answer (score 17):

In phpMyAdmin 4.0, you go to Status > Monitor. In there you can enable the slow query log and general log, see a live monitor, select a portion of the graph, see the related queries and analyse them.

[image]

Comment: Huh? What? There are 6 graphs, which do I select? Where under Monitor is the control to enable the slow query log and general log?  How do you "select a portion of the graph and see related queries" when dragging the mouse over the graph doesn't do it? This answer couldn't be much vaguer. I really wish, given that PHPmyAdmin apparently doesn't work properly out of the box, there was some instruction somewhere that simply told newbies how to see the log so we could at least begin to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XAMPP as your server, you'll find a logs directory as a child of the XAMPP directory. If you have not tried XAMPP, which runs on any system (Windows, Mac OS & Linux) find more here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: after 12 years this answer helped me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use performance_schema database and the tables:

1. events_statements_current
2. events_statemenets_history
3. events_statemenets_history_long

Check the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-event-tables.html)