# How can I see the queries getting executed for given database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

As with SQL Server, we can use a profiler to see queries getting executed against given database, How can we achieve the same in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to view past mysql queries with phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247229/is-there-a-way-to-view-past-mysql-queries-with-phpmyadmin) But ist not marked as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer belove link hope its work for you

[How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)