# Accidently Emptied Tables in the Wrong Database (Using PHPMyAdmin for MySQL), Anyway to Restore Data?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, restore

As the title states, I accidently emptied tables in the wrong database. I did not export the database before I did this (stupid me). Is there anyway to restore the database to a previous date/version, so that I may obtain the emptied data back?

Comment: Yes. Restore from your backups. Oh, right - you don't have one. You're out of luck. There's no magic wand that will create a backup after the fact that you can restore now. There is an upside, though - I'll bet you won't forget to back up your data going forward. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to recover deleted data if you didn't make any backups. You could try to check the logs, but I doubt you will find anything. You have to be careful when handling important data.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039799/where-can-i-find-mysql-logs-in-phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for you, but you should automate your mysql backup (in this case you lose at worst one day of data). I use this script to do that : https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/
HTH