# How to check the Phpmyadmin logs?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, angular, phpmyadmin

In Phpmyadmin

1. is there any possible to check the logs (error logs, process log) ?? Except the console - history option
2. What changes done recently in the table or database and who has done the change??

Answer (score -1):

Open your PHPMyAdmin, don't select any database and look for Binary Log tab . You can select different logs from a drop down list and press GO Button to view them.

Duplicated question: [Where can I find MySQL logs in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039799/where-can-i-find-mysql-logs-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: This incorrect "answer" has been posted all over SO. There is no "Binary Log" tab anywhere in PHPMyAdmin, whether you select a database or not.